# Process multiple files with awk

Tags: awk, syntax

I would like to count the number of points in each interval. I have the positions of the points in the first file and the intervals in the second. First I store the point attributes in two arrays(pos and name) and then i want to loop over them in order to determine wheter it belongs to the given interval ($1 is the name and $2 is the start and $3 is the end of the interval). I have the following code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{name[NR]=$1;pos[NR]=$2;next}; {for (i in name) if (name[i] == $1 && pos[i] >= $2 && pos[i] <= $3) {sum[NR] += 1;}} END {for (i = 1; i <=length(sum); i++) {print sum[i]}} file1 file2 > out'
```

I have a syntax error: "syntax error near unexpected token `i"

I am beginner in awk. Any help is highly appriciated. Thanks

```
awk '
NR==FNR{
  name[NR]=$1
  pos[NR]=$2
  next
}
{
  for(i in name){
    if(name[i] == $1 && pos[i] >= $2 && pos[i] <= $3){ sum[FNR] += 1; }
  }
}
END {
  for(i = 1; i <=FNR; i++){
    print sum[i];
  }
}
' points windows > output
```

```
points:

chr1    52
chr1    65
chr2    120
chr2    101
chr2    160
chr3    20
chr4    50

windows:

chr1    0   100
chr1    100     200
chr2    0   100
chr2    100     200
chr3    0   100
chr3    100     200
chr4    0   100
chr5    0   100
chr6    0   100
chr6    100     200
chr7    0   100
chr8    0   100

gave me the desired output:

2


3
1

1
```

Thank You

Comment: Please also provide minimum example input files.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Sorry it is a research work in the field of bioinformatics. The input files are enourmous, i was just curious about the syntax. But you are right next time i provide some small input files.

Comment: We can get rid of your syntax error easily enough but without a [mcve] that includes concise, testable sample input and expected output we can't help you fix your script to actually do whatever it is you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `'` is in wrong place and `awk` command is not ending properly, could you please try following. Couldn't test it since no samples are given.

`awk 'NR==FNR{name[NR]=$1;pos[NR]=$2;next}; {for (i in name) if (name[i] == $1 && pos[i] >= $2 && pos[i] <= $3) {sum[NR] += 1;}} END {for (i = 1; i <=length(sum); i++) {print sum[i]}}' file1 file2`

Non-one liner form of above solution.

```
awk '
NR==FNR{
  name[NR]=$1
  pos[NR]=$2
  next
}
{
  for(i in name){
    if(name[i] == $1 && pos[i] >= $2 && pos[i] <= $3){ sum[NR] += 1 }
  }
}
END{
  for(i = 1; i <=length(sum); i++){
    print sum[i]
  }
}
' file1 file2 > out
```

As per sir @Ed Morton 's comment following could be few recommendations: Again these are not tested since no samples were given but you could try to apply them.

- `sum[NR]` should be as `sum[FNR]` if in case you want to put index as per line number of Input_file2, why because difference between `NR` and `FNR` is that `NR`'s value will be keep keep increasing till all Input_file(s) are read but `FNR` value will be RESET to `1` whenever there is new Input_file is being read.
- Then, `length(sum)` could be value of `FNR` because basically you may be looking for total number of times loop has to run which you could get by `FNR` value.